# Get date for nth day of week in nth week of month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column with values like '3rd-Wednesday', '2nd-Tuesday', 'Every-Thursday'.

I'd like to create a column that reads those strings, and determines if that date has already come this month, and if it has, then return that date of next month.  If it has not passed yet for this month, then it would return the date for this month.

Expected results (on 4/22/16) from the above would be: '05-18-2016', '05-10-2016', '04-28-2016'.

I'd prefer to do it mathematically and avoid creating a calendar table if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to post some sample data  and exepected output.Data you posted is of not much help

Comment: Based on the sample data which may have more conditions, this would require complex string operations. it's better to handle this on application layer than in SQL Server.

Comment: What should happen if the value doesn't exist at all in the current or next month? E.g. 5th Friday will only exist every few months. When asking date related questions, you should carefully consider edge cases (e.g. February and/or months with 30/31 days in them) and enumerate how you want such edge cases to be dealt with. It shows that *you've* put some thought into the requirements, rather than expecting us to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Partial answer, which is by no means bug free.

This doesn't cater for 'Every-' entries, but hopefully will give you some inspiration. I'm sure there are plenty of test cases this will fail on, and you might be better off writing a stored proc.

I did try to do this by calculating the day name and day number of the first day of the month,  then calculating the next wanted day and applying an offset, but it got messy. I know you said no date table but the CTE simplifies things.

### How it works

A CTE creates a calendar for the current month of date and dayname. Some rather suspect parsing code pulls the day name from the test data and joins to the CTE. The where clause filters to dates greater than the Nth occurrence, and the select adds 4 weeks if the date has passed. Or at least that's the theory :)

I'm using `DATEFROMPARTS` to simplify the code, which is a SQL 2012 function - there are alternatives on SO for 2008.

```
SELECT * INTO #TEST FROM (VALUES ('3rd-Wednesday'), ('2nd-Tuesday'), ('4th-Monday')) A(Value)

SET DATEFIRST 1

;WITH DAYS AS (
    SELECT 
    CAST(DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),N.Number) AS DATE) Date, 
    DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),N.Number)) DayName 
    FROM master..spt_values N WHERE N.type = 'P' AND N.number BETWEEN 0 AND 31
)
SELECT 
    T.Value,
    CASE WHEN MIN(D.Date) < GETDATE() THEN DATEADD(WEEK, 4, MIN(D.DATE)) ELSE MIN(D.DATE) END Date
FROM #TEST T
JOIN DAYS D ON REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(T.VALUE), 1, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(T.VALUE)) -1)) = D.DayName
WHERE D.Date >=
    DATEFROMPARTS(
        YEAR(GETDATE()), 
        MONTH(GETDATE()),
        1+ 7*(CAST(SUBSTRING(T.Value, 1,1) AS INT) -1)
        )
GROUP BY T.Value



Value         Date
------------- ----------
2nd-Tuesday   2016-05-10
3rd-Wednesday 2016-05-18
4th-Monday    2016-04-25
```

Comment: Thanks, Les! This got me very close.. Am tweaking it now and will post final query when finished.